# Create DATETIME in MariaDB using LocalDateTime column type in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot-starter

I need create `DATETIME` column in MariaDB using `LocalDateTime` column type in JPA.

I created this entity:

```
@Column
private LocalDateTime created_at;
```

but when I depot the code the column in MariDB is updated to `DATE`. I need `DATETIME`.

I also tried this:

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private LocalDateTime created_at;
```

But when I deploy the code I get error:

```
@Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property
```

I use Java 10 and `spring-boot-starter-parent`

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```

Is there any solution to this problem? For example is there a way to set the column type into the entity as `DATETIME` without using `@Temporal`?

Comment: Are you sure you used LocalDateTime in your try without @Temporal because LocalDateTime should be DATETIME in the db. When I tried it with spring-boot-starter-parent, it worked.

Comment: It turns out that DATETIME was created - I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store a `LocalDateTime` in a `TIMESTAMP` column, you need to implement the mapping to `java.sql.Timestamp`.

You need to implement the [AttributeConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) interface.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
        return (locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code but during deployment I get again @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property

Comment: You should define attribute without @Temporal.

Comment: So just keep @Column

Comment: I tried but this creates DATE column in MariaDB. I need DATETIME column

Comment: The JPA persistence unit needs to know about the converters. This can be done by adding the converters to the persistence.xml.

Comment: I added  @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class) before the column declaration but during deployment I get the exception.

Comment: what exception?

Comment: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property

Comment: remove @Temporal